# Angular-ngCordova - Gelocation returns undefined when it's inside a function

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ngCordova plugin called "geolocation", this plugin returns the user's device location [Latitude , Longitude ] it works fine if the code was  like this

```js
app.controller('MotionController', function ($scope, $cordovaDeviceMotion, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation)
{



var posOptions = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false };
            $cordovaGeolocation
                .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
                .then(function (position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude
                    var long = position.coords.longitude
                    console.log("Latitude: "+lat )
                }, function (err) {
                    // error
                })
                
                
     })
```

And i got the correct value in the console ..

But the problem is , when i put that  code inside a function like this

```js
app.controller('MotionController', function ($scope, $cordovaDeviceMotion, $ionicPlatform,  $cordovaGeolocation)
{
    
   

        var UserLatitude;
        function getLocations() 
        {
            var posOptions = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false };
            $cordovaGeolocation
                .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
                .then(function (position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude
                    var long = position.coords.longitude
                    UserLatitude = lat;
                }, function (err) {
                    // error
                })
                
             return UserLatitude;

        }

        console.log("Latitude is:"+getLocations())
       


    })
```

once I called that function , i got "Latitude is: undefined " in the console 
How that happens ?

Comment: may be device ready is not fired.

Comment: add some logs to your success and error callbacks and see what you get. Also log UserLatitude after you set it to lat to make sure it actually got set.